# Activiti BPM - recurring time interval error in boundary timer

Tags: activiti, business-process-management, iso8601

In a boundary timer, I set a time cycle following ISO 8601 to execute every minute limited to 3 repetitions:

**R3/2016-02-23/PT1M**

Everything works fine, after 3 minutes the timer doesn't execute anymore. But if I remove the number of repetitions:

**R/2016-02-23/PT1M**

after a minute, the boundary timer starts to execute **every less than a second**, I mean, in a few seconds the timer has been executed thousand of times. What am I doing wrong?

Activiti version: 5.17.1

Answer (score 0):

Alright, according to Joram Barrez -core developer of activiti- this bug was reported and then fixed in a later release.

I've tested activiti version 5.20.0.1 and everything works fine. [Here](https://forums.activiti.org/comment/33371#comment-33371) you can find Joram's answer.